# Error en la nevegación con routes

Tags: flutter, dart, rutas

Estoy intentando que se muestre una pantalla en base a la siguiente condición.

```
prefs.userData.isEmpty ?'/':'/home'
```

`prefs` se obtiene de la información que esta en `SharedPreferens`.

Si el usuario no tiene datos guardados se le muestra `DatosPage` si ya existen datos guardados como primera pantalla debe mostrar `HomePage`

clase `MyApp` con el `MaterialApp` con `routes`

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  /// indicar con que pantalla se debe iniciar,
  /// * si no hay datos inicia [DatosPage]
  /// * si ya hay datos inicia [HomePage]
  final prefs = new PrefsUser();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',

      initialRoute: prefs.userData.isEmpty ?'/':'/home',
      routes: {
        '/'       : (context) => DatosPage(),
        '/home'   : (context) => HomePage(),
        '/carrito': (context) => CarritoPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

El problema es que entra a `HomePage` pero mostrando un botón de regresar el cual no esta en mi código como si ubiera hecho un `Navigator.push()` el cual regresa a `DatosPage`lo cual no debería pasar.

Comment: agrega más código, para saber como invocas a la ruta

Comment: @diegoveloper la verdad no se que mas código agregar, podría incluir donde inicializo las preferencias o todo lo que contiene el `MaterialApp`

Comment: esto  prefs.userData.isEmpty ?'/':'/home'  donde lo pones? por default debe entrar a DatosPage , luego que pasa?

Comment: @diegoveloper Una ves entrado a `DatosPage` se ingresan los datos a guardar en `_prefs.userData` y pasamos a `HomePage` el cual solo se muestra si ya hay datos en _prefs.userData

Comment: esa parte del código en como redirecciones de pagina puedes ponerla?

Comment: @diegoveloper Agregue la acción del botón al guardar los datos. puedo colocar todo el código de ser necesario ya que es un proyecto personal de aprendizaje(también esta en un github como privado actualmente)

Comment: Muestra todo el materialapp

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109798/discussion-between-diegoveloper-and-richard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sucede algo interesante cuando usas una ruta con el path de '/', este path es interpretado por Flutter como la ruta por defecto, por lo que primero pasa por esa ruta siempre.

Para solucionar el problema tienes 2 opciones:

1 - Cambia el path de `'/': (context) => DatosPage()` a `'/datos': (context) => DatosPage()`

o

2 - Haz la validación del preference dentro de `DatosPage` y luego un pushReplace , solo que esto no se vería bien porque se mostraría por unos milisegundos la pantalla de Datos , ahí podrías aplicar un splashscreen.

Answer (score 0):

Intente Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, '/home'), con esto debe de eliminar la primera pantalla de datos y dejar solo la de home y el appbar no debe de agregar opcion de regresar

Comment: Gracias, pero el problema se presenta al inicial la app para la navegación que mencionas utilizo `pushReplacementNamed` eso elimina el boton de regresar, es después de que se guardan los datos, pero ya guardados no debería pasar por `DatosPage`